# Django : How to get longitude and latitude from google maps user selected adress and save to database

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and Python.
I want to make a view in which user can open the google maps ( or anything similar), choose a location (put a thumbtack) on map and get the longitude and latitude from this location to save to database.
I searched the internet but i am confused about how to do it

Can you please , guide me where to look or what to use?
Many thanks for spending your time to help me

Kostas

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions. Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you want to use BING API see this for same http://helpdoc.info/how-to-get-latitude-longitude-by-using-address-from-bing-api/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google has an API key to access  google-map

```
 api_key = "Your private key for google map here"
 address="address of the selected user"
 api_response = requests.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={0}&key={1}'.format(address, api_key))
        api_response_dict = api_response.json()
```

this will search the address on the map and give you a response back to the 'api_response' variable
from this variable you can access the longitude and lattitude of the address given above

```
api_response_dict = api_response.json() # this line used to covert the response into a dict format/json format

latitude = api_response_dict['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
longitude = api_response_dict['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for the answer. I want my program open google maps and user find the location he wants. When put the sticker on google map page , then I want the the longitude and lattitude. Can I do this with the code you provide?

Comment: NO, the above code will use to get the longitude and latitude using google map if we can pass an address

Comment: Have you got any idea where too look to find a solution?

Comment: please go with JS to do the things what you need

Answer (score 0):

The Bing Maps APIs include map controls and services that you can use to incorporate Bing Maps in applications and websites. In addition to interactive and static maps, the APIs provide access to other geospatial features such as geocoding, route and traffic data and spatial data sources that you can use to store and query data that has a spatial component, such as store locations.

Step 1: Create a Bing Maps Key

Step 2: Run Python Script

Source : http://helpdoc.info/how-to-get-latitude-longitude-by-using-address-from-bing-api/